# How accurate is the timer in java?

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm basically scheduling a task to run every ten seconds, but it seems like it runs every 8 or 9. I use the function schedule (task, 0 , 10000);

Comment: is this running on android or a server?

Comment: How did you calculate the time it took to start executing ? Try an accurate method like calculating the difference between the start & end time using `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: A slow task can effect the timing. From the Java docs: "Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes."

Comment: You could try using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with postDelayed() instead of Timer

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's pretty accurate. In my app(Tap Counter) I use a timer to start a task, and a seperate timing system to display a countdown, and they sync perfectly.

Feel free to check out my app =)

Answer (score 0):

try the Alarm Service to schedule a task.

Hope this links will be helpful http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html